# Add wrapper objects to prototype object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function used as a constructor.

All the functions used are added to the `prototype` object of the function.

However, because there are so many of them, i was curious if i could "group" them into some wrapper objects. If i do this, the `this` instance of the constructor function gets lost.

```
function FilesManager() {
    this._init();
};
FilesManager.prototype._init = function () { };

// wrapper object for folders functions
FilesManager.prototype.folders = {};
FilesManager.prototype.folders._dropFiles = function () {
    var self = this;
    // self is an instance of folders {} object, and not an instance of FilesManager
};
```

Comment: Group them by prefixes or by separating them in the source code, but not by nesting properties.

Comment: The function class would have about 50 methods, for `folders`, `files`, `properties` etc, and i was looking for a way to group the functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re use prototype of Folders but have to create an instance of Folders to have a reference of the instance of FileManager that uses it. Code can look something like this:

```
function Folders(fileManager){
  this.fm=fileManager;
}
Folders.prototype._dropFiles=function(){
  //test to see if we get the correct name
  console.log("logging name:",this.fm.name);
}
function FilesManager(args) {
  if(typeof args==="undefined"){
    args={};
  }
  this.name=args.name?args.name:"default name";
  this.folders=new Folders(this);
};

var fm1=new FilesManager({name:"fm1"});
var defaultNamedfm = new FilesManager();
fm1.folders._dropFiles();
defaultNamedfm.folders._dropFiles();
```